# Como trabajar con llaves foraneas en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Estoy realizando un proyecto, en el cual necesito que los datos de un model los pueda usar en otro.

El primer models es este:

```
class Product(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
price = models.FloatField()
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/photos')

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

En el segundo, el de ofertas, serian los mismos datos pero con uno nuevo, new_price.

Como quedaria el models de ofertas?

Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: @Alfabravo Hola! Ya tengo varias preguntas en la plataforma, no subi el codigo porque puse el nombre de los datos en texto, pero pondre el codigo. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podría ser:

```
class Oferta(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
new_price = models.FloatField()
```

De esta forma cuando crees una oferta le pasas el producto junto con el precio del producto en oferta. Solo debes configurar la relación de acuerdo al comportamiento que deseas y agregar los campos adicionales que necesites.